# TypeScript: Return instance of class from an interface method

Tags: typescript

How can I specify the return type of an interface method to be an instance of the class implementing the interface in TypeScript? For example:

```
interface Entity {
  save: () => ClassThatImplementsEntity
}
```

so that a class implementing `Entity` interface will have a save method that returns instance of that class

```
class User implements Entity {
  save() {
    // some logic
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: Usually interface should not know about the implementation. Could you explain why do you need something like this?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types

Comment: @dm.shpak I need it to make the method chainable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually your interface should not know about the implementation, but if **save()** should return exactly the type of class you can use **this**

```
interface Entity {
  save: () => this
}

class E1 implements Entity {
    save() {
        return this
    }
}

class E2 extends E1 {

}
const e1 = new E1()
const e2 = new E2()
const x1 = e1.save() // type of x1 is E1
const x2 = e2.save() // type of x is E2
```

It looks like it is something you need